# Using the result of MATCH function as a cell identifier in excel

Tags: excel, function, match

I am attempting to sort a list of names alphabetically in excel. Users enter names in no particular order.

Here are the steps I have taken that work so far.
- Names are stored in sheet 'Staff List' under column B.
- In 'Staff List' column A, the order names should be in is calculated using

```
=COUNTIF($B$1:$B$79, "<="&B1)
```

This returns the correct order that names should be in
Ex. Bob, Billy, Jane. Values would be 2, 1, and 3.

Next, Match is used to determine which row contains the correct name to be used.

```
=MATCH(1,'Staff List'!$A$1:$A$100,0)
```

For the above example, this would return 2 which again works fine.

Now the problem is how do I actually use this to list out the names properly? I thought I could simply make a function that goes like:

```
='Staff List'!B(MATCH(1,'Staff List'!$A$1:$A$100,0))
```

I expected this to turn into:

```
='Staff List'!B2
```

However, the match isn't turned into a value and generates an error. How can I solve this?

(I hope my formatting and everything is alright for my first post :D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use INDEX:

```
=INDEX('Staff List'!B:B,MATCH(1,'Staff List'!$A$1:$A$100,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Index function like below to fetch column B information:

`=INDEX('Staff List'!$B$1:$B$100,MATCH(1,'Staff List'!$A$1:$A$100,0))`